# Pyglet - Stop a song from playing

Tags: python, pyglet

I am playing a song as specified in the docs and it all works brilliantly. But how do I stop a song and clear the queue?

Thanks

Oscar

Comment: Show us some code so we know what we are working with. That makes it easier to formulate a bit more specific answer.

Comment: read this first
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283067/python-playing-music-with-pyglet-and-gui

Answer (score 1):

The specs at http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/controlling_playback.html say that there is no stop method and that to stop a song and clear the queue you have to, quoting "simply pause playback and discard the player and source objects". If you need to keep playing songs after this you would create a new player object.